# Can I (temporarily) disable an internal USB device to free up endpoints?

Tags: windows, usb, usb-3

Relevant specs are:
 - Windows 10 64-bit
 - Intel USB 3.0 XHCI host controller

For those unaware, the Intel USB 3.0 XHCI controller [can host a maximum of 96 USB endpoints](https://plugable.com/2015/09/08/not-enough-usb-controller-resources/). Each USB hub and device consumes 1 or more of these endpoints. This is the hard limit on how many USB devices your controller can support.

I am planning on hosting four thin clients off my computer for a tech summer camp. This will require connecting many USB devices simultaneously, so I need to make sure enough endpoints are available.

However, after using [this tool](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/usb-device-tree-viewer-download), I have discovered that my computer has two *internal* USB devices - a Bluetooth radio and a webcam - which combined, use over 20 out of the 96 endpoints. I don't need either for my summer camp. So my question is:

Can I, within Windows, temporarily disconnect/disable these internal USB devices such that their endpoints will be freed up for other devices?

Comment: It depends on how you disable them.  If they are integrated into the motherboard, then even when the device is disabled in Windows, in all likelihood they will still use those endpoints.  It sounds like you need to use a PCI-E USB 3.0 card and connect the Thin clients to those (although I have never heard of connecting thin clients via USB)

Comment: @Ramhound, I am not sure if the integrated or not-integrated matters. The limitation seems to come from controller capability, although the information is 3 years old, when Intel didn't have a fully-functional xHCI controller. Resources are allocated by driver on connect basis, so once you disable a device, the slot resources should be free. This is an interesting issue, I need to look into this.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the ideas. The reason these will be thin clients over USB is that I will be given access to a computer lab space, but I almost definitely won't have permission to install the requisite software/drivers on their computers, and my personal computer may not even be able to connect to the local network. If you've got any other ideas though, please let me know!

Comment: Isn't distance would be a problem to communicate over USB3, depend on quality of cables I have got maximum 3-12 meters at high speed...

Comment: @Alex 4 or 5 meters would be enough. As I said in a previous comment, the reason I'm considering this is access restriction of the computer lab this will be taking place. (I don't work in the school district, the IT is absentee, etc). These are ridiculous hoops to have to jump through to host the camp, but right now I'm just exploring my options.